# Identity of the rooster

Tags: tractate-brachot

The [Gemara Berachos (7a)](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.7a.16?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&lang=bi&with=Ben%20Yehoyada&lang2=en) writes

> וְאֵימַת רָתַח? אָמַר אַבַּיֵי: בְּהָנָךְ תְּלָת שָׁעֵי קַמָּיָיתָא
> כִּי חִיוָּרָא כַּרְבַּלְתָּא דְתַרְנְגוֹלָא וְקָאֵי אַחַד כַּרְעָא.
>
> The Gemara asks: When is the Holy One, Blessed be He, angry? Abaye
> said: God’s anger is revealed through animals. During the first three
> hours of the day, when the sun whitens the crest of the rooster and it
> stands on one leg. When it appears that its life has left him and he
> suddenly turns white, that is when God is angry.

Is there a particularly special rooster this refers to or does every rooster do this each morning in sync? (I was also wondering if it might be connected to the red rooster whose waste is singled out among the birds as being particularly foul regarding davening [Shulchan Aruch 79:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.79.26?lang=bi&p2=Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.79&lang2=bi))

Comment: Mashma it's talking about all roosters

Comment: At the very least, it's a rooster that was readily available to R. Yehoshua Ben Levi.

Comment: I just want to correct you Regarding the red roster 'תרנגול אדומי' in Shulchan Aruch (סימן עט סיף ו) simple means a Turkey. See Kitzur Shulcan Aruch סימן ה:סיף ו: next to צואת תרנגול אדומי in parenthesis it says תרנגול הדו which is a Turkey, not a Roster. I know this is going on your Shulchan Aruch 79:6 because The Kitzur brings down your Siman 76 at the end of the סימן ה:סיף ו as (סימן עט וסומן פו).